# Parsing data and inserting values into mysql database using php?

Tags: php, mysql, json

> Php code to check if json data is coming from the android code.

```
<?php
require "init.php";
if($_POST){
 print_r($_POST);
}else{
 echo "Nothing came from android code";
}
?>
```

In response I am getting json data as follows :-

> (
>   [jsonarray] => [{"custInfo":"Ujwal  9975022560","rate":"24000","weight":"21.00000","desc":"GENTS ANGTHI 22k NO STONE","makingAmt":"200","sum_total":"RS.156283.38","vat":"RS.3064.38","itemTotal":"51073","barcode":"BQSP78BB","net_rate":"24200","date":"2015-12-02","invoiceNo":"1","bill_type":"Invoice"},{"custInfo":"Ujwal  9975022560","rate":"24000","weight":"21.00000","desc":"GENTS ANGTHI 22k NO STONE","makingAmt":"200","sum_total":"RS.156283.38","vat":"RS.3064.38","itemTotal":"51073","barcode":"BQSP78BB","net_rate":"24200","date":"2015-12-02","invoiceNo":"1","bill_type":"Invoice"},{"custInfo":"Ujwal  9975022560","rate":"24000","weight":"21.00000","desc":"GENTS ANGTHI 22k NO STONE","makingAmt":"200","sum_total":"RS.156283.38","vat":"RS.3064.38","itemTotal":"51073","barcode":"BQSP78BB","net_rate":"24200","date":"2015-12-02","invoiceNo":"1","bill_type":"Invoice"}]
>   )

What I want to do is parse this response and insert the data into mysql database.I think something like this.

```
foreach ( $data as $inv ) {
    $custInfo = $inv->custInfo;
    $rate =     $inv->rate;
    $weight=    $inv->weight;
    $desc=      $inv->desc;
    $makingAmt= $inv->makingAmt;
    $vat=       $inv->vat;
    $itemTotal= $inv->itemTotal;
    $sum_total= $inv->sum_total;
    $barcode=   $inv->barcode;
    $net_rate=  $inv->net_rate;
    $date=      $inv->date;
    $invoiceNo= $inv->invoiceNo;
    $bill_type= $inv->bill_type;
    $sql = "INSERT INTO selected_items 
             (custInfo, invoiceNo, barcode, desc, 
              weight, rate, makingAmt,net_rate,
              itemTotal,vat,sum_total,bill_type,date) 
            VALUES
             ('$custInfo','$invoiceNo','$barcode','$desc',
              '$weight','$rate','$makingAmt','$net_rate',
              '$itemTotal','$vat','$sum_total','$bill_type','$date')";
    $res = mysqli_query($sql,$con);
```

I am new to php so I tried json_decode but it returns a empty string in response. How can i parse and insert `custInfo, invoiceNo, barcode, desc,weight, rate, makingAmt,net_rate,itemTotal,vat,sum_total,bill_type,date` into my table `selected_items.`

Thak you :)

Comment: @NanaPartykar Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this(Updated):

```
$arr = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['jsonarray']), true);
$env = $arr['jsonarray'];
```

Comment: but how do i get the individual values from inside the array.I am new to php please help

Comment: oh you already have written the code to loop $env array , you can use that

Comment: Piyush I am still getting back an empty response.I tried your code.

Comment: are you sure that the  posted response is not null ? if the $_POST itself is null than you will get empty response

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96770/discussion-between-androidnewbee-and-thepiyush13).

Comment: can you please check my php code I have msg'd it to you :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$myArray = json_decode($data, true);


 $sql = "INSERT INTO selected_items 
             (custInfo, invoiceNo, barcode) 
            VALUES
             ('$myArray['custInfo'],$myArray['invoiceNo'],$myArray['barcode'])";
    $res = mysqli_query($sql,$con);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit: added some error checks to help debug the code.**

You could try decoding it directly to an array using [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

then yo can use [extract()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) **Import variables into the current symbol table from an array**, this does away with the **foreach** loop.

```
<?php
    require "init.php";
    if($_POST){
        $data = $_POST;
        $array = json_decode($data, true);

        if($array===NULL){return print_r('json decode failed!');}
        if(!is_array($array)){return print_r('Well, the decoded data is corrupt, its supposed to be an array, '.gettype($array).' given!');}

        if(!isset($array['jsonarray'])){return print_r('no json data was ever received!');}
        extract($array['jsonarray']);

        $sql = "INSERT INTO selected_items 
         (custInfo, invoiceNo, barcode, desc, 
          weight, rate, makingAmt,net_rate,
          itemTotal,vat,sum_total,bill_type,date) 
        VALUES
         ('$custInfo','$invoiceNo','$barcode','$desc',
          '$weight','$rate','$makingAmt','$net_rate',
          '$itemTotal','$vat','$sum_total','$bill_type','$date')";
$res = mysqli_query($sql,$con);

    }else{
        echo "Nothing came from android code";
    }
?>
```

Comment: When I print the $_POST directly i get a response but when I try to use json_decode the response is blank

Comment: test the return value of Json_decode, it returns the value encoded in json in appropriate PHP type, or null when json cannot be decoded or if the encoded data is deeper than the recursion limit.

Comment: when i used this I got a response $arr = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['jsonarray']), true);

Comment: Something like this Array
 (
     [0] => Array
         (
             [custInfo] => Ujwal  9975022560
             [rate] => 24000
             [weight] => 21.00000
             [desc] => GENTS ANGTHI 22k NO STONE
             [makingAmt] => 200
             [sum_total] => RS.156283.38
             [vat] => RS.3064.38
             [itemTotal] => 51073
             [barcode] => BQSP78BB
             [net_rate] => 24200
             [date] => 2015-12-02
             [invoiceNo] => 2
             [bill_type] => Invoice
         )

Comment: Now how do i parse it

Comment: you can extract the keys to variables using php's extract() function, i.e extract($arr[0]); then continue with the SQL statement

Comment: Can you give an example

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96771/discussion-between-platinum-industries-and-androidnewbee).